# Change Icon from FontAwesomeIcon on Function (onChange Text Input)

Tags: reactjs

I'm thinking about changing the icon which is set using the fontawesome-react package depending on a previous user interaction.

On screen the user has a input field and button (which contains an icon). If the Input is empty a different icon is presented

**No User Input:**

```
+-----------------------+-----------+
| Search Placeholder... | (Shuffle) |
+-----------------------+-----------+
```

**User Input:**

```
+-----------------------+-----------+
| Value                 | (Search)  |
+-----------------------+-----------+
```

when setting the icon manually inside the `<FontAwesomeIcon>` I'm able to find `faSearch`, When however setting it using state I get the error:

```
Could not find icon {prefix: 'fas', iconName: 'faSearch'}
```

Here's my take so far. I'd be really happy if someone is able to assist and is able to explain what I'm missing.

```
class Search extends React.Component {

  state = {
    displayIcon: "faSearch",
  }
  
  onChange(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value)

    if(event.target.value === ''){
      this.setState({
        displayIcon: "faShuffle",
      })
    } else {
      this.setState({
        displayIcon: "faSearch",
      })
    }
  }

  render(){
    const { displayIcon } = this.state //destucture state

    console.log( );
    return (
      <>
      
        <InputGroup className="mb-3">
        <FormControl
          placeholder="search or feel lucky..."
          onChange={this.onChange}
        />

        <Button variant="primary" id="search" size="lg">
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={displayIcon} />
        </Button>

        </InputGroup>
      </>
    )
  }

}
```

Comment: are you sure that `faSearch` is part of `fas`? not from `fal`, `far`, `fab`, etc?

Comment: if I use `<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSearch} />` the search icon get's displayed just fine. same as for `<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faShuffle} />` I'm not quite sure where it picked up `fas`

Comment: check my answer to use a string instead an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also do that like this and render it conditionally:

```
class Search extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: '',
  };

  onChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      value: event.target.value,
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { value } = this.state; //destucture state

    return (    
        <InputGroup className='mb-3'>
          <FormControl placeholder='search or feel lucky...' onChange={this.onChange} />

          <Button variant='primary' id='search' size='lg'>
            {value ? <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSearch} /> : <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faShuffle} />}
          </Button>
        </InputGroup>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: this almost did the trick, I was having an issue with setState which I could fix with changing onChange into an arrow function.

Comment: ```onChange = async (e) => {this.setState({value: e.target.value,});}```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of passing an object you could try to pass a string for `fa-search` like so:

`<FontAwesomeIcon icon='fas fas-search` />

The implementation in `onChange` being:

```
if(event.target.value === ''){
      this.setState(
        'fa fa-shuffle', // don't know this one check it on https://fontawesome.com/v5/icons/random?s=solid
      )
    } else {
      this.setState(
        'fas fas-search'
      )
    }
```